# Can i use query Parameters in choice router?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am curious to know if this is allowed or not.

I want to add an expression to a choice router and I am not sure if i am going about this the correct way.

I made the query attributes into variables through a transform message component then tried to use them in my expression.

If i use

`#[attributes.queryParams.'environment' != null ]`

then i get results but i need to add more choices to this router

I have tried to use the following but it sends me into the default choice.

`#[attributes.queryParams.'environment' == attributes.queryParams.'dev']`

&

`#[attributes.queryParams.'environment' == vars.dev]`

Comment: When using this type of notation in most languages, you don't need the dot.  So it would be attributes.queryParams["dev"]

Comment: You can use in choice router, there is nothing wrong with your code. @sean i don't agree with it `["dev"]`. try and print other queryParams before using == operator, so you will know what you are routing across. I find an interesting article how we abuse choice router, worth of reading it https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-style-guide-stop-abusing-choice-router/

Comment: Ive come to find out this is the working result                                                          #[attributes.queryParams.'environment' == "dev"]

Comment: Are you solved your question?